# Restrict aws api access to a particular ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

Hi is there anything possible to restrict access to aws api where lot of people have admin access to aws.
I want people that have admin/normal access have read only access from anywhere but when they want to change anything they should login to a particular machine and now they can change with there aws credentials.

Comment: create role-based user instead of the admin user. creating every user with admin role is not recommended 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html

Comment: Not every user atleast some people have admin access and I want to restrict for them

Answer (score 2):

Your policy that grants access to the API calls would `Allow` two sets of permissions:

- One set that grants **read-only access**
- Another that grants **Admin access, with a condition that restricts by IP address**

To grant permissions only when accessed from a certain IP address range, use something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "<whatever actions you are granting>",
    "Resource": "<whatever resources you are permitting>",
    "Condition": {"IpAddress": {"aws:SourceIp": ["192.0.2.0/24"]}}
  }
}
```

Comment: Great I'll give it a try and one more thing user has admin access it can change the role also that means it can remove the conditions right ? Is there any way to also restrict this ?

Comment: Best is _not_ to give admin access, then only grant the permissions they should have. Alternatively, use a `Deny` to remove the permissions unless they access via the IP address range. See: [AWS: Denies Access to AWS Based on the Source IP - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_aws_deny-ip.html)